# Improperly formatted define flag: EDIT _ flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-debug, flutter-exception

What is the issue below? Recently updated flutter, then got this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I have solved this issue by changing my folder path it has '...ADD, EDIT, SAVE' in the folder name. So that might be the issue. I just changed the folder name and solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also resolve this by shortening the path directory.
Copy the project folder/file and paste in the desktop or any shorter directory. Re-import the project into Android Studio or your IDE and debug and overwrite the existing project. It worked for me. Thanks.