# Improperly formatted define flag: Dart)\jurnal11\lib\main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Im newbie about this flutter, dart and also android studio but i got this error every time i try to run project with android emulator

[image: This Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [Improperly formatted define flag: EDIT _ flutter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67937650/13603811), maybe you should try to move your project to other directory with shorter path. Copy the project folder/file and paste in the desktop or any shorter directory, then re-import the project into Android Studio or your IDE and debug and overwrite the existing project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).