# How to resolve error in 'flutter.gradle' line 1201 that prevents app execution on devices?

Tags: flutter

How to solve the error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where: Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

here is the code for line 1201:

```
project.exec {
            logging.captureStandardError LogLevel.ERROR
            executable flutterExecutable.absolutePath
            workingDir sourceDir
            if (localEngine != null) {
                args "--local-engine", localEngine
                args "--local-engine-src-path", localEngineSrcPath
            }
            if (verbose) {
                args "--verbose"
            } else {
                args "--quiet"
            }
            args "assemble"
            args "--no-version-check"
            args "--depfile", "${intermediateDir}/flutter_build.d"
            args "--output", "${intermediateDir}"
            if (performanceMeasurementFile != null) {
                args "--performance-measurement-file=${performanceMeasurementFile}"
            }
            if (!fastStart || buildMode != "debug") {
                args "-dTargetFile=${targetPath}"
            } else {
                args "-dTargetFile=${Paths.get(flutterRoot.absolutePath, "examples", "splash", "lib", "main.dart")}"
            }
            args "-dTargetPlatform=android"
            args "-dBuildMode=${buildMode}"
            if (trackWidgetCreation != null) {
                args "-dTrackWidgetCreation=${trackWidgetCreation}"
            }
            if (splitDebugInfo != null) {
                args "-dSplitDebugInfo=${splitDebugInfo}"
            }
            if (treeShakeIcons == true) {
                args "-dTreeShakeIcons=true"
            }
            if (dartObfuscation == true) {
                args "-dDartObfuscation=true"
            }
            if (dartDefines != null) {
                args "--DartDefines=${dartDefines}"
            }
            if (bundleSkSLPath != null) {
                args "-dBundleSkSLPath=${bundleSkSLPath}"
            }
            if (codeSizeDirectory != null) {
                args "-dCodeSizeDirectory=${codeSizeDirectory}"
            }
            if (extraGenSnapshotOptions != null) {
                args "--ExtraGenSnapshotOptions=${extraGenSnapshotOptions}"
            }
            if (extraFrontEndOptions != null) {
                args "--ExtraFrontEndOptions=${extraFrontEndOptions}"
            }
            args ruleNames
        }
    }
}
```

---

Error that generated :

```
Where:
Script 'C:\Users\lin37\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
```

- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\lin37\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           22.4s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me by shortening the directory which is the project in  it,

you can shorten the directory either by changing a file name if it is big (the way I used) or you can just move the project to another shorter directory.

I got the fix from this question: [Improperly formatted define flag: EDIT _ flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830807/improperly-formatted-define-flag-edit-flutter)

Hope it helps.